Docker Compose: Mounted Laravel's .env File Not Passing Environment Variables (Laravel, MySQL)
I'm trying to connect my Dockerized Laravel application to a MySQL database using Docker Compose. I've mounted the .env file that contains the DB_DATABASE variable, but I'm still encountering the error:
Folder structure:

docker-compose.yaml

Error

Here's my setup:

I have a Laravel project with a .env file containing DB_DATABASE and other environment variables.
I have a docker-compose.yml file that defines a service for MySQL and references the environment variables from .env.
I've mounted the.env file into the container using the volumes section in docker-compose.yml.

My question is:

How can I make mysql environment use the ${DB_DATABASE} from Laravel's .env. Are there any known issues with this approach?


Is this a pure problem of the MySQL container? Please share all details (like the configuration files and error logs) in text form, and adjust the tagging

It seems there are multiple problems with your docker-compose file.
1.Please make sure your env file path is correct. If the path is right you don't even need the environment property in mysql service, make sure the env file contains these variables:
In .env:
MYSQL_DATABASE=
MYSQL_USER=
MYSQL_PASSWORD=
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=

In docker-compose.yml:
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: tap-and-stack-db
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  env_file:
    - ./dockerize/tap-and-stack/.env

2.Obsolete version of docker-compose. You have to specify a newer version (I use 3.9 but there are many).
version: "3.9"

3.There is a typo at the restart property, it should be:
restart: unless-stopped

4.The network laravel_environment is missing, you can create it like this in docker-compose:
networks:
  laravel_environment:
    driver: bridge


Heya. Thanks, I fixed that typo haha  I'm still facing "variable is not set" error tho, as you can see in my updated post, I added my folder structure. I tried to create .env file in the root directory and yes, the docker-compose detected it but that's not what i wanted. I need my docker-compose to use the .env file inside the root directory of the tap-and-stack folder and I think the path I declared in my docker-compose is correct, but still I am getting "variable is not set".
